# Is it possible to do pattern matching without case?

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

I'm still learning SML, so my apologies if this is a rather dumb question. I was wondering if there was a better way to do pattern matching on some constructs outside of functions.

For example, let's say we have a type

```
type coord = int * int * int
```

And then we have some value `b` of type `coord`. I understand that we can do pattern matching in functions, for example:

```
fun get_x_coord ((x, y, z) : coord) = x
```

But let's say we're working with `b` inside of another function not given as a parameter. I feel like doing

```
case b of
  (x,y,z) => (* do stuff *)
```

is rather clunky if I have a single result that I want (for example I know there will be three integer values and I just want to isolate them).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you can use pattern matching in `val`-bindings too, so you could do something like this:

```
fun foo (b : coord) =
  let val (x, y, z) = b
  in (* do stuff *)
  end
```